# How to access nested JSON Response in android?

Tags: android, arrays, json

This is a JSON, I got results(Values) from colorArray but i can't able to get results from shapeArray. How to get results from shapeArray ? How to get shapeArray values ? How to manage these type of nested JSON responses ?

```
[
    {

            "colorArray":[
                    {
                    "colorName":"red",
                    "hexValue":"#f00"
                },
                    {
                    "colorName":"green",
                    "hexValue":"#0f0"
                },
                    {
                    "colorName":"blue",
                    "hexValue":"#00f"
                },
                    {
                    "colorName":"cyan",
                    "hexValue":"#0ff"
                },
                    {
                    "colorName":"magenta",
                    "hexValue":"#f0f"
                },
                    {
                    "colorName":"yellow",
                    "hexValue":"#ff0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "shapeArray":[
                {
                    "shapeName":"circle"
                },
                {
                    "shapeName":"square"
                },
                {
                    "shapeName":"triangle"
                },
                {
                    "shapeName":"hexagon"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

**Code**

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
{ jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); 
 JSONArray jsonColorArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("colorArray"); 
 for (int j=0;j<jsonColorArray.length();j++)
  { JSONObject colorObj = jsonColorArray.getJSONObject(j);
  String colorName = colorObj.getString("colorName");
   String hexValue = colorObj.getString("hexValue"); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: My Code : for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONArray jsonColorArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("colorArray");

                            for (int j=0;j<jsonColorArray.length();j++){

                                JSONObject colorObj = jsonColorArray.getJSONObject(j);
                                String colorName = colorObj.getString("colorName");
                                String hexValue = colorObj.getString("hexValue");
                            } }

Comment: what problem are you facing ?

Comment: I can't able to get shape array values. How to get shapeArray values from Json array?

Comment: shapearray is 1 position

Comment: JSONArray jsonShapeArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("shapeArray"); this gives null pointer exception

Comment: Thanks  IntelliJ Amiya. Now only i realized ur answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all very bad json design. Second

> JSONArray jsonShapeArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("shapeArray");

will give you error as there is no such object. Try using this :

> JSONArray jsonArray = parent.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("shapeArray");

Here parent is your root jsonArray.

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. Thank you adnaan.zohran

Answer (score 0):

```
  JSONArray jsonColorArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("colorArray"); 
  JSONArray jsonShapeArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("shapeArray"); 
 for (int j=0;j<jsonColorArray.length();j++)
 {
   JSONObject colorObj = jsonColorArray.getJSONObject(j);
   String colorName = colorObj.getString("colorName");
  String hexValue = colorObj.getString("hexValue"); 
 } 
 for (int k=0;k<jsonShapeArray.length();k++)
 {
   JSONObject shapeObj = jsonShapeArray.getJSONObject(k);
   String shapeName = shapeObj.getString("shapeName");

 }
```

Hope this help you...if you need any help you can ask

Comment: Thanks but JSONArray jsonShapeArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("shapeArray"); gives exception

Answer (score 0):

> `jsonObject.getJSONArray()` always gives a `NullPointerException` because the two `JSONArray` name is
>   different.
>
> Since you're Iterating the `JSONArray` You can handle the exception
>   like this

```
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonText);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonColorArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("colorArray");
                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonColorArray.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject jsonColorObject = (JSONObject) jsonColorArray.get(j);
                        String colorName = jsonColorObject.getString("colorName");
                        String hexValue = jsonColorObject.getString("hexValue");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException ex) {

                }

                try {
                    JSONArray jsonShapeArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("shapeArray");
                    for (int k = 0; k < jsonShapeArray.length(); k++) {
                        JSONObject jsonShapeObject = (JSONObject) jsonShapeArray.get(k);
                        String shapeName = jsonShapeObject.getString("shapeName");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException ex) {

                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I modified your code with little bit changes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
                if (jsonResult != null) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    try {
                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResult);

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONArray jsonColorArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("colorArray");
                            for (int j=0;j<jsonColorArray.length();j++){

                                JSONObject colorObj = jsonColorArray.getJSONObject(j);
                                String colorName = colorObj.getString("colorName");
                                String hexValue = colorObj.getString("hexValue");
                            }

                            JSONArray shapeArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("shapeArray");
                            JSONObject shapeObject = jsonObject.getJSONArray("shapes").getJSONObject(i);

                            for (int k = 0; k < shapeArray.length(); k++) {
                                JSONObject jsonShapeObject = (JSONObject) shapeArray.get(k);
                                String shapeName = jsonShapeObject.getString("shapeName");
                            }
                        }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); }
```